# What do dots mean when Apache Ivy is downloading something?

Tags: java, ivy

I use Apache Ivy for dependency management and just wondered what those dots mean in the console while it is downloading something.

This is what I mean:

```
[ivy:retrieve] downloading http://www.smartclient.com/maven2/com/smartgwt/smartgwt/3.0/smartgwt-3.0.jar ...
[ivy:retrieve] ..............
[ivy:retrieve] ...................
[ivy:retrieve] .......................
[ivy:retrieve] ......
[ivy:retrieve] ..............
[ivy:retrieve] ..............
[ivy:retrieve] .....................
[ivy:retrieve] ........
stripped
[ivy:retrieve] ..... (10070kB)
[ivy:retrieve]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.smartgwt#smartgwt;3.0!smartgwt.jar (136197ms)
```

I Googled on it but have not found the definition. Bandwidth? But Sometimes it writes very long lines that even wrap over.

Comment: They mean "wait, I has more bytes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dots represent the number of times [`InputStream.read(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) was called (using a byte array size of 64Kb) while downloading the artifact.

The Ivy [`FileUtil`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/util/FileUtil.java) `copy(InputStream, OutputStream, CopyProgressListener, boolean)` ultimately transfers the artifact bytes to a local file and in turn notifies the [`AntMessageLogger`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/ant/AntMessageLogger.java) of download progress. Its `doProgress()` method emits the `.`s and has a comment:

> log with ant causes a new line -> we do it only once in a while

So it tries to limit output to only emit a log message about every 1500 milliseconds.